# not able to assign value to object, it is in undefined state

Tags: angular

I am invoking web API service, while debugging I am able to fetch values.
But when trying to assign value, the object is in an undefined state.

*this.selectedEvent = x;*

**this.selectedEvent** is in undefined state.

In service file, there is the method as given below to return event as per the id

```
getEvent(id: String){
        return this.http.get(environment.baseApiURL + '/api/event/getevent/'+id)
        .map(data => data.json() as Event);
      }
```

and this is where I am calling the service
event.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { EventService } from "../../event/shared/event.service";
import { Event } from "../shared/event.model";
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import {BrowserModule, DomSanitizer} from '@angular/platform-browser'


@Component({
  selector: 'event-detail',
  templateUrl: './event-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./event-detail.component.css'],
  providers: [EventService]
})
export class EventDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedEvent : Event;
  loading: boolean = false;

  constructor(public eventService: EventService, private route: ActivatedRoute){
    this.selectedEvent = new Event();
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.eventService.getEvent(params['id']).subscribe(x=>{
        this.selectedEvent = x;
        this.loading = false;
      });
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: What does "object is in undefined state" mean? You're not displaying/printing anything in the code you posted. Please post code displaying something, tell us what you expect to be printed, and what is printed instead.

Comment: Inside  ngOnInit() method, I am assigning event i.e. x to the this.selectedEvent object. While checking in debugger I am getting value in x. But this.selectedEvent is in undefined state

Comment: Again, what does that mean. How is the class Event defined? What do you expect `this.selectedEvent` to contain, and what does it contain instead? Post actual and expected outputs. post the relevant code.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is a very common problem faced by Angular developers.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.eventService.getEvent(params['id']).subscribe(x=>{
        this.selectedEvent = x;
        this.loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
```

Here `this.selectedEvent = x;` is written inside subscribe() which means it's only scope is inside of this function.

What you can do to get the value of `this.selectedEvent` is you can call a function from within the subscribe() and pass the x.

Here is an Example:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.eventService.getEvent(params['id']).subscribe(x=>{
        this.getSelectedEvent(x);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    });
  }
getSelectedEvent(x){
   this.selectedEvent = x;
}
```

Comment: This is not correct. Because it is using fat arrow syntax (`x => {}`) it retains the scope of the class. This would only be true if it was using `function(x) {}`, and even then you would be unable to call `this.selectedEvent` because of the scope.

Comment: You can assign the value to this.selectedEvent inside the subscribe() but you won't be able to access it outside the subscribe, this is because subscribe is a method, and x=>{} is a call back fat arrow function which is binded to the (this) of subscribe and not the class.

Comment: Sorry, that is not correct at all. One of the key selling points of arrow functions is that it prevents the need for `bind` in callbacks

Comment: thanks man, I am able to assign values to selected event
but still it is not displaying values in html page


<div class="well">
      <p>
        {{selectedEvent.eventName}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{selectedEvent.eventDescription}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{selectedEvent.eventStartDate}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{selectedEvent.eventEndDate}}
      </p>
      <p>
        {{selectedEvent.venueId}}
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>

Comment: Exactly @pprajapati , you will be able to assign the values to the selected event but only within the scope of Subscribe() and to bind them with the html u need then to be global to that class, try using my solution, it will work, don't worry.

Comment: @kartikchawla hey can you help me, even though selectedEvent is global to that class and also it is being assigned in getSelectedEvent like you mentioned. It is not being displayed in html file. it is empty

Comment: Try printing it outside subscribe() it will say undefined because it is out of scope of subscribe(); try the method i told u... that is call a function from inside the subscribe and sent x as parameter

Comment: ngOnInit() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.eventService.getEvent(params['id']).subscribe(x=>{
         this.getSelectedEvent(x);
        this.loading = false;
      });
    });
    console.log(this.selectedEvent) //doesn't display here 
  }

  getSelectedEvent(x){
    this.selectedEvent = x;
    console.log(this.selectedEvent) //display here
 }
as a result it is not showing in html, why this is happening

Comment: Can you share what exactly is printed when you display this.selectedEvent in the getSelectedEvent function..?